# Gradle build failing saying 'A problem occurred evaluating project ':black-box-tests' '

Tags: java, gradle, npm

Setting up new project and gradle build is failing

On building gradle project using ./gradlew clean build

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':black-box-tests'.
> Could not find method testCompile() for arguments [{group=, name=, version=3.40.2}, build_a1xitdmjl7u2lfav5f3r9hxej$_run_closure2$_closure4@5cd5463d] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

Here is the output for gradlew host:run

```
> Configure project :black-box-tests
The testCompile configuration has been deprecated for dependency declaration. This will fail with an error in Gradle 7.0. Please use the testImplementation configuration instead. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#dependencies_should_no_longer_be_declared_using_the_compile_and_runtime_configurations
        at build_a1xitdmjl7u2lfav5f3r9hxej$_run_closure2.doCall(/...black-box-tests/build.gradle:8)
        (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)
The compile configuration has been deprecated for dependency declaration. This will fail with an error in Gradle 7.0. Please use the implementation configuration instead. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#dependencies_should_no_longer_be_declared_using_the_compile_and_runtime_configurations
        at build_a1xitdmjl7u2lfav5f3r9hxej$_run_closure2.doCall(.../black-box-tests/build.gradle:22)
        (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)

> Configure project :collector
The testRuntime configuration has been deprecated for dependency declaration. This will fail with an error in Gradle 7.0. Please use the testRuntimeOnly configuration instead. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#dependencies_should_no_longer_be_declared_using_the_compile_and_runtime_configurations
        at junit5_bzzps2bxgawzs7p64egzueei4$_run_closure5.doCall(.../gradle/junit5.gradle:34)
        (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)

> Configure project :core-test
The compile configuration has been deprecated for dependency declaration. This will fail with an error in Gradle 7.0. Please use the implementation or api configuration instead. Consult the upgrading guide for further information: https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#dependencies_should_no_longer_be_declared_using_the_compile_and_runtime_configurations
        at build_11rlzchwcskw357vfuyehcaj3$_run_closure1.doCall(.../core-test/build.gradle:5)
        (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)

> Configure project :{project_name}
Using insecure protocols with repositories has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. Switch Maven repository 'maven2(http://.../nexus/content/groups/public)' to a secure protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol for more details.
        at coverage_c3gwax8xe4qmpr6tiyqqw1slj$_run_closure4$_closure10.doCall(...gradle/coverage.gradle:28)
        (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)
Using insecure protocols with repositories has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. Switch Maven repository 'maven3(http://.../nexus/content/repositories/bintray)' to a secure protocol (like HTTPS) or allow insecure protocols. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.UrlArtifactRepository:allowInsecureProtocol for more details.
        at coverage_c3gwax8xe4qmpr6tiyqqw1slj$_run_closure4$_closure10.doCall(.../gradle/coverage.gradle:28)
        (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)
The AbstractArchiveTask.version property has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. Please use the archiveVersion property instead. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.AbstractArchiveTask.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.AbstractArchiveTask:version for more details.
        at build_24gz6alkwfofft19kj8geimac$_run_closure1.doCall(.../build.gradle:28)
        (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)
The Project.libsDir property has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. Please use the libsDirectory property instead. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:libsDir for more details.
        at coverage_c3gwax8xe4qmpr6tiyqqw1slj$_run_closure4$_closure10.doCall(.../gradle/coverage.gradle:28)
        (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)

> Configure project :
current branch: master
Gradle version: 6.7.1The AbstractArchiveTask.baseName property has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. Please use the archiveBaseName property instead. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.AbstractArchiveTask.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.AbstractArchiveTask:baseName for more details.
        at build_ecotjj08nhxxisberrz2yw8by$_run_closure3$_closure20.doCall(.../build.gradle:193)
        (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

build.gradle(for the project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url ".../nexus/content/groups/public" }
        maven { url ".../nexus/content/repositories/bintray" }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE"
        classpath "....platform.xas:xas-gradle-plugin:1.0.20"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties:gradle-git-properties:1.5.2"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties'
apply from: '../gradle/junit5.gradle'
apply from: '../gradle/rpm-upload.gradle'
apply from: '../common.gradle'

mainClassName = "project_name"


jar {
    baseName = ""
    enabled = false
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(":core")
    implementation project(":connector")
    implementation project(":collector")
    implementation project(":ui")

    implementation "org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:${hibernateValidatorVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:${springBootVersion}"

    implementation "...common:lol:2.0.5"

    implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}") {
        exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache:${springBootVersion}"

    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow:${springBootVersion}"
    implementation "io.undertow:undertow-core:2.0.16.Final"
    implementation "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2"
    implementation "commons-io:commons-io:2.6"
    implementation "com.google.guava:guava:${guavaVersion}"
    implementation "org.codehaus.janino:janino:3.0.10"
    implementation "com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:2.9.2"

    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}"
    testImplementation "...:rc-restassured:${rcRestAssuredVersion}"
    testImplementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:${okHttpVersion}"
    testImplementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:${okHttpVersion}"
    testImplementation "org.zeroturnaround:zt-zip:${zipUtilVersion}"
    testImplementation "com.atlassian.oai:swagger-request-validator-restassured:2.0.0"

    testImplementation project(':core-test')
    testImplementation 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.19'
    testImplementation 'org.jdom:jdom2:2.0.6'
    testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}"
}

bootDistZip.enabled = false
bootDistTar.enabled = false
distTar.enabled = false
distZip.enabled = false
```

build.gradle(for UI)

```
plugins {
    id "com.github.node-gradle.node" version "3.1.1"
    id 'java-library'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1"
    implementation "org.springframework:spring-web:${springVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:${springVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:${springVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:${springVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:${springVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:'2.0.1.RELEASE'"
    implementation  group: 'org.springframework.security.oauth.boot', name: 'spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure', version: '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    implementation project(":connector")
}

node {
  version = '8.11.1'
  npmVersion = '5.6.0'
  download = true
}

task webpack(type: NodeTask, dependsOn: 'npmInstall') {
  def osName = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
  if (osName.contains("windows")) {
    script = project.file('node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js')
  } else {
    script = project.file('node_modules/.bin/webpack')
  }
}

jar.dependsOn 'webpack'
clean.delete << file('node_modules')
```

Have installed node and npm and setting up the classpath for the same.

What could possible be added for this?